# jquery mobile event taphold on image

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I added 'taphold' jquerymobile event for an image. When i taphold on that image in ipad i am getting the below pop up which is thrown by browser. How to avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helps

```
  img
  {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a long shot but try CSS rule

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

It may prevent the popup from appearing.

Hope it helps :)